# Подчеркивание волнистой красной линией

Tags: c#, плагин, internet-explorer

Cейчас занимаюсь разработкой плагина под IE на c# - проверка орфографии. Встала необходимость подчеркивать в `textarea` красной волнистой линией неправильные слова. Стандартными средствами html, css, js сделать не получается (или не додумался, как?). Один выход - рисовать программно. Но не совсем представляю, как это реализовывается. Может, у вас есть какие-то идеи или свой живой опыт в данной проблеме?

Answer (score 1):

Вот нашел на просторах интернета:

```
<style type="text/css">

.wavyline
{
 background: url(wavyline.gif) repeat-x 100% 100%;
 padding-bottom: 2px;
 text-decoration: none;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
</style>

<span class="wavyline">ошибок</span>
```

Ссылка на саму гифку http://mike.mchedlishvili.me/my-includes/css/images/wavyline.gif

Answer (score 0):

Стандартный textarea не позволяет накладывать расширенное форматирование на текст, и маловероятно, что с помощью каких-либо возможностей javascript это реализуется. Есть два выхода:

1. взять готовый редактор текста, вроде [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/),
2. использовать [contenteditable](http://html5demos.com/contenteditable) из HTML5 ([Content editable в HTML5](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/html5/126877/)).

Comment: Вы не так поняли. Я пишу плагин, он программными средствами должен подчеркивать неправильно написанные слова. Плагин для IE8 (никакой html5). 
В браузере грузится страничка, в ней, допустим, есть textarea, так вот плагин должен подчеркнуть слова с ошибками. html, css, javascript я упомянул, как вариант внедрения кода в полученную от сервера страницу, но как вы и сказали, этими средствами форматировать текст в textarea нельзя.
Поэтому, перефразирую вопрос: "Как из c# можно нарисовать красную волнистую линию под неправильными словами в IE8? Сохраняя отрисовку при скроллинге и т.д."

Answer (score 0):

Если то, что вы делаете, - это разработка плагина на Silverlight, то вы можете создать поле для ввода текста внутри самого плагина (richtextbox), тогда вы сможете использвать стандратные методы и свойства [контрола](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox(v=vs.95).aspx) для выдлеления и стилизации текста

```
textbox.Text = "Это произвольный текст";
textbox.Select(4, 12);
textbox.SelectionFont = new Font(textBox.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Underline);
```

Comment: Нет, разработка идет на чистом c#. Контролов, кроме как предоставленных самим Internet Explorer-ом (т.е. html, а именно - <textarea></textarea>) нету! Да и Ваша реализация подчеркнет текст обычной прямой линией. А мне надо волнистой, красной.